# Excel formula for aggregation and filtering

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to aggregate values on one excel tab and display on another tab?
In addition to that can we also filter on one of the columns as we aggregate?

For example, Sheet1 has 3 columns - (Continent, City, Ignore)

```
Continent   City       Ignore
Europe      Paris       N
Europe      London      N
Europe      Liverpool   N
Europe      Rome        N
Europe      Oslo        Y
Asia        Tokyo       N
Asia        Osaka       N
Asia        Dubai       N
Asia        Bangkok     Y
Asia        Mumbai      N
Africa      Cairo       Y
```

I want my Sheet2 to display the number of cities per continent taking into account the "Ignore" flag.

```
Continent  #Cities
Europe      4
Asia        4
Africa      0
```

Since 3 Cities are marked as Ignore=Y, we don't want to count them.

It came as one of the recommended pivot tables, but I'm trying to build this using excel formulas so I can build on that if needed.
Prefer excel formulas over VBA or Macro.

Comment: use `COUNTIFS()` probably is your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your sample data...

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12,E2,$C$2:$C$12,"N")
```

Drag down...